# Joining current token with previous in a vector array (or any collection)

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am working on building rule based Named Entity Recognizer and the problem I am facing is this:

I am able to identify all the proper nouns in a text but the way they get identified is what I am having issues with.

E.g "Rhode Island based Atrion Corporation" gets outputted as [[Rhode],[Island],[Atriaon],[Corporation]]

I am building rules to combine proper nouns occuring together and identify them as one entity but I am iterating over every word in a chunk/clause and adding the identified proper noun into a vector. Is there a way I could join elements in a vector or any collection for that matter to get an output like:

[[Rhode Island], [Atrion Corporation]]

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

So I've added the rules and am using a string builder to build the string and then add the proper nouns, however, my results still aren't ideal. Now I get something like:

[ Rhode Island Atrion]

Here is my code:

```
Vector<String> nnpTokens = new Vector<String>();
    Set<String> NNPs = new HashSet<String>();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Vector <Integer> nnpIndexes = new Vector<Integer>();

            for( int i = 0; i <= chunk.getSize(); i++)
            {

                NLWord word = chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i);

                //NNP followed by NNP
                if(i < chunk.getSize() && (word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS")) && (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                        || (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS"))))
                {
                    builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    continue;

                }
                //NNP preceded by NNP
                if( i > 0 && (word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS")) && (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                        || chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS")))
                {
                    builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(word.getToken());
                    //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    continue;

                }

                //NNP followed by a prep/cc relation 
                if( i < chunk.getSize() && (word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS"))
                        &&  (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("for") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("of") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("and"))){

                    builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(word.getToken());
                    //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    continue;

                }

                //NNP preceded by a prep/cc relation 
                if( i > 0 && (word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS"))
                        && (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("for") 
                        ||  chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("of") 
                        ||  chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("and"))){

                    builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(word.getToken());
                    //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    continue;

                }



                if(word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS") && (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                        || (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS"))))
                {

                    //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    builder.append(" ");
                    builder.append(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    continue;
                }


                if (i > 0 && (word.getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("for") || word.getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("of") 
                            || word.getToken().equalsIgnoreCase("and")) && (chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                            || chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS"))){

                        //nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                        builder.append(" ");
                        builder.append(word.getToken());
                        nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                        continue;
                }

                if( i < chunk.getSize() && i > 0 && (word.getPostag().equals("NNP") || word.getPostag().equals("NNPS")) 
                        && !(chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS")) 
                        && !(chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("NNP") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("NNPS")) 
                        && !(chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("PRP") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i + 1).getPostag().equals("CC"))
                        && !(chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("PRP") 
                        ||   chunk.getTokens().elementAt(i - 1).getPostag().equals("CC"))){
                    nnpTokens.add(word.getToken());
                    nnpIndexes.add(word.getIndex());
                    continue;

                }
                else 
                    continue;
            }

            //String newNNPTokens = builder.toString();
            NNPs.add(builder.toString());
            NNPs.addAll(nnpTokens);
            //System.out.println("NNPs:" + NNPs);
            nnpTokens.clear();


       //System.out.println(NNPs);
       return NNPs;
    }
```